# installing python in Ubuntu

Tags: python

I wanted to install python 3.4.2 through the terminal and it asks for my password. I started to type but nothing appears. how do I give my password?

Comment: Just type the password and hit enter . It will never be visible but the terminal is taking in the password

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will appear since there is no `echo` feedback when you type your password. When it asks for the password, just type it and press the `enter` key.

Answer (score 0):

just type your password and press enter.password is not visible in terminal